# trying to make a menu for a program and run a specific function

Tags: function, nameerror

i am trying to make a fortune cookie program and i need a menu, then the chosen option's function will be executed. i get an error when i try to run the code, i need to be able to run the function that is chosen (i have only written the code for option 1 as i came across this error: (i need to append the new fortune onto the end of the text file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\work\computing\fortune cookie\fortunecookie.py", line 9, in 
    if option == 1:
NameError: name 'option' is not defined

```
def menu():
    print "Your options are: "
    print "1-Add a new fortune"
    print "2-Tell my fortune"
    print "3-Exit"
    option = raw_input("What do you want to do?")

menu()
if option == 1:
    addfortune()
elif option == 2:
    tellfortune()
elif option == 3:
    exitProgram()
else:
    print("Invlaid menu choice")
    menu()

def addfortune():
    newfortune = input("What is the new fortune?")
    f = open("fortune.txt","w")
    f.write(str(newfortune))
    f.close()
    menu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tries to access a variable from the global scope.

```
def menu():
    global option
    ...
```

The above code should do it.
Read more about scopes [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Maby try to return that value instead of using a global variable:

```
def menu():
    ...
    return option
```

And turn your conditions accordingly to it.

Some opinions about global variables: [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/python-why-are-global-variables-evil)